# How can I get a bank statement for tourist visas while traveling?

Tags: legal, money, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm planning to travel around South America for around 9-12 months.
My passport is very weak and i need a visa for almost anywhere in the world.

Currently residing not in my origin country and can't apply for all visas in advance cause don't want to set the strict route.
Want to apply for visas while traveling.

All tourist visas require at least 3 months old Bank Statements. 
I have an active bank account only in a current country of residency. So every time i will apply for a visa from other country they ask for a statement.

I will not be able to physically get a statements from Thai bank account, only print myself using online banking, which i suppose will not be acceptable.

**Question:**
Any solution for this? 
Or the only way is to open a bank account in each country right after arrival and wait for 4 months (funds transfer + visa application) in each place?

**Update:**
So far i'm on the way of finding a particular solution. There are a few banks you can work with remotely, which also provide a ways to get a paper statement remotely. Moreover, some legal firms do provide similar services.

Comment: A number of countries are unwilling to issue visas unless you apply from a country where you are resident. Some countries are more lax, but even then, applying from far away doesn't help your case: getting a visa requires showing ties to your home, and so applying far away from home can be a red flag. In short, you'll want to research whether all the countries involved will actually accept your visa applications if you apply while traveling.

Comment: IIRC I am not able to get printed statements at all from my bank, so there has to be a way to do with just printed online banking PDFs.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the consulates in question won't accept statements printed from online banking, especially from a well-known international bank?

Comment: This is the opposite of the answer of what you're looking for, but I'd thought I'd share it anyway. https://medium.com/@nramirez/why-i-stopped-traveling-while-working-remotely-in-south-america-6cc8cef0a34a

Answer (score 3):

What might work is to get a bank account at a well-known international bank (like Citibank or Barclays or Chase) that has branches in the countries you plan to  visit. The branches might be willing to work with you to either provide you a printed statement or certify your online statement.

Comment: Yeah something like that. Thanks, opened this topic exactly to hear about such kind of particular solutions.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: Any solution for this?

Yes, the solution is simple: issue a **power of attorney** to a friend of yours in Thailand, authorizing them to receive a certified copy of your bank statements, which they would then mail to South America. But even if you do have a copy of your bank statements there might be an issue with applying for a visa in a country where you're not a resident. Some consulates are strict about it, others are not. Check the exact rules for each consulate in advance so that you're not surprised on your trip - I assume you would have to do at least a little bit of planning before arrival.

On an unrelated note - the long-term solution is to stick to one country and become a citizen there. If the country has a strong passport it would completely resolve your visa issues for the future.

Comment: Yeah that will be a solution, but not planning to keep using current bank. Anyway, so i found a possible solutions so far. This topic wasn't really helpful except by judging my views :D Simply don't want to stick to one country at this point (talking about citizenship). Back to the topic - Did quite a lot of research at the moment, there are a few banks you can work with completely remotely, which can also ship statements worldwide + some legal companies providing a similar service. Will post an answer once get a particular solution.

Comment: I'm sorry for sounding like I was judging your views; I was not. I have removed the answer.

Comment: @HankyPanky no problem :)
About applying from the countries where i'm not a resident - yeah, know about that, planning according with it. Thanks for mentioning.